# How to Cluster Power Spectral Dencity Matrix (in Time-Frequency Domain) using DBSCAN to get 2 clusters of data and noise

Tags: signals, classification, cluster-analysis, wireless, dbscan

I have a 2000-by-286 matrix which have 2000 time observations of 286 frequencies. i want to get 2 clusters. one for data signals and one for noise. i'm using DBSCAN to do that but in result i'm getting only one cluster of noise. I think DBSCAN is taking all the data as noise. Please help me what should i do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try different parameters.

In particular epsilon **must** be chosen to fit your distance function and data set. There is no good default called.

Comment: parameters like what?

Comment: Distance function, minpts, and epsilon. But there is no option to choose the number of clusters to be 1, obviously. Noise is not a cluster.